# Jackson XML parsing - Two possible types of data (Android, Kotlin)

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse XML to kotlin class using Jackson and it's working fine, but schema says for example:

```
<xs:element name="Center" type="PointType">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Represents a 2D or 3D Center Point</xs:documentation>
<xs:documentation>
Defined by either a coordinate text value ("north east" or "north east elev") or a CgPoint number reference "pntRef" attribute.
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

So center can be parsed to PointType class or can be also just a String.

```
//...
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName="Center")
    var center: PointType? = null,
//...
```

This code working well but when I try with example where is just String (two numbers separated by space) then I have

> Exception
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of...

Is it possible to for example ignore this error and add second field typed as String or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found is change type to "Any" in schema. 
And then later is possible to cast it using "as".